# Product and coproduct in the category of pointed sets..

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I have the category $C$, where:

objects are nonempty sets with one fixed element $Obj = \{(A,a)$, where $A$-nonemty sets, $a\in A\}$,

morphisms are $Mor=\{ f:(A,a)\rightarrow (B,b)$; where $f$ - is a mapping from $A$ to $B$ and $f(a)=b\}$.

How can I prove that for every two elements of $C$ there exists their product but not the coproduct?

I know both definitions but still don't know how to prove it. Is there any standard way of proof?

Comment: This category in fact has products and coproducts. But perhaps the point is that the products are the same as in $\mathbf{Set}$ and the coproducts are not.

Comment: I might be wrong, I don't know why It seemed to me that coproduct in such category doesn't exist. 
So how to prove that there actually exists a product and coproduct?

A product is dual to coproduct, so is it enough to prove the existence of only one of them?

Comment: What is the coproduction in the category of Sets? How could you modify that to get a coproduct in $\mathcal C$?

Comment: I know that the product in the category of Sets is their cartesian product, but I'm not sure what the coproduction is.

Comment: @DeltaDelta: coproduct in Sets is *disjoint union*, and it is almost disjoint union in the category of pointed sets, but you have to 'glue' the two basepoints together.

Comment: If you don't know what a coproduct looks like in $\mathbf{Set}$, you don't know what coproducts are.  You won't be able to solve this exercise unless you understand coproducts.  So go back to your book and reread the part with basic examples of  coproducts until you understand what coproducts look like in $\mathbf{Set}$ and in two other categories. If your book doesn't explain that example and two others, get a different book that does have examples.

Comment: "A product is dual to coproduct, so is it enough to prove the existence of only one of them?" Not at all, generally speaking. The existence of products will only prove that coproducts exist in the *opposite* category, unless some other special conditions hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The product of $(A,a)$ and $(B,b)$ in the category of pointed sets is $(A \times B,<a,b>)$ with the same projections and mediating morphism as in $\mathcal {Set}$. You can easily prove this, basically by noticing that projections and mediating morphism respect the basepoints $a,b$ and $<a,b>$.

Regarding the coproduct:

The coproduct od $(A,a)$ and $(B,b)$ in the category of pointed sets is $(A \bigsqcup B/\sim  ,*)$ where $\sim$ is the equivalwence relation identifying $<a,0>$ with $<b,1>$ and calling them "*".
The injections and mediating morphism are modified from $\mathcal {Set}$ accordingly. For ex. the injection $i_A$ takes $a$ to * and any other $p$ to $<p,0>$.

Comment: I'm trying to prove this result is valid not only for two objects, but for all family of them. Could I use a similar approach?

Comment: I think so . You can also use an induction argument

Comment: I mean, even for an uncountable family...